# Adding an image to a button in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I am making an HTML5 video player, but I need to put a play icon on my button and the old method no longer works. Also, I cannot use `background-image:url('Filename');` because I also have a gradient, and when I add the `background-image` it overrides my gradient. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do what twitter bootstrap does and use an `<i class="some-icon-class"></i>` in the content to easily add icons.

the CSS for that `<i>` tag is set to a block with a certain height and width, and has a background image.

they use it like this:

```
<button ...><i class="plus-icon"></i> Add New Item</button>
```

check it out: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons

Comment: Where you have "Add New Item", is this where I would put my image tag? But I will definitely try this method.

Comment: no, you dont use an image tag at all. you apply a background image to the CSS of the `<i>` tag itself.

Comment: Will this override my gradient?

Comment: it shouldn't. twitter bootstrap's buttons have gradients in addition to the actual icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what your button element tag is exactly. But since you say "html5" I will assume you are using the actual "button" tag. Maybe try this:

```
<button onClick="eventHandler();"><img src="button_image.png" /></button>
```

Or perhaps you are looking for "more proper" html5 where img tag is not used and all styling is strictly in the CSS?

Comment: Yes, an actual button tag. I want to put an image on that and keep my gradient.

Comment: Ok, cool. So if putting a nested img tag is ok for you, then use png or gif  with transparency for most of the button image. Just put a little icon in the middle and possibly some borders or shadows around the image edges.